# Receive data json/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Good evening!

Trying to learn how to receive data with **json/JQuery** using following function. I've managed to store the php variable in a json variable (var ar), and it seems to contain what I want (according to `console.log`, `document.write` says `[object Object]`) but I'm not sure how to implement it in the function.

Comment: Can you add before the `$.each()`, this line: `console.log(data);` and let us know what it shows in Console or FireBug if you're using it.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Sounds like your JQuery is not loading. Can you edit and include more of your code?

Comment: Missing this: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the reason for your implementation, but if you are just processing data from a post, it would probably be more efficient to parse the JSON via PHP not with jQuery.

I have made a simple example about retrieving JSON data and parsing the result data, 1 key at a time. Depending on your JSON schema you may have to parse each key differently as they may have different children nodes.

```
var url = "http://beta.json-generator.com/api/json/get/EkRU_ItZl";

$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        $('#result').append("Key:" + key + " Value:" + JSON.stringify(val) + "<br/>" );
    });
});
```

Here is a basic example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DJRavine/k8cxn4u9/

I hope this helps out.